# How do I get these lines of boxes created?

Tags: tikz-pgf, loops

I cannot find out what I am missing. I am basically trying to have two and a half lines of boxes right next to each other but somehow a10 is supposed to be missing. Can anyone help?
Thanks in advance!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance = 0pt,
    square/.style = {draw=blue!60, fill=blue!5, very thick, 
        minimum height=3em, minimum width=3em, % <---
        outer sep=0pt},
    square2/.style = {draw=red!60, fill=red!5, very thick, 
        minimum height=3em, minimum width=3em, % <---
        outer sep=0pt},
    ]
    \node[square] (a00) {};
    \foreach \i in {0,1}{
        \foreach \j in {1,2,3}{
            \pgfmathsetmacro\k{\j-1}
            \node[square,right=of a\i\k] (a\i\j) {};        
        }
        \pgfmathsetmacro\k{\i+1}
        \node[square,below=of a\i0] (a\k0) {};
        
    }
    
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently `\pgfmathsetmacro` returns floating point results. You need integer values in order for your code to work. Use `\pgfmathtruncatemacro` instead. Here follows your code adapted so that no error is produced. However, there may be another error. You wrote

> I am basically trying to have two and a half lines of boxes right next to each other

but this produces two lines of four boxes each plus one single box in the third line. This may be what you want and yet it may not.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance = 0pt,
    square/.style = {draw=blue!60, fill=blue!5, very thick, 
        minimum height=3em, minimum width=3em, % <---
        outer sep=0pt},
    square2/.style = {draw=red!60, fill=red!5, very thick, 
        minimum height=3em, minimum width=3em, % <---
        outer sep=0pt},
    ]
    \node[square] (a00) {};
    \foreach \i in {0,1}{
        \foreach \j in {1,2,3}{
            \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\k}{\j-1}
            \node[square,right=of a\i\k] (a\i\j) {};
            %\pgfmathsetmacro\kk{\j-1}
            %\node[square,right=of a\i\k] (a\i\j) {\textbackslash kk= \kk, \textbackslash k = \k};
        }
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\k}{\i+1}
        \node[square,below=of a\i0] (a\k0) {};
    
    }

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Above code yields the following:

[image: Result of above code.]

Addition:
The reason why the error was not thrown earlier is that for the first line nodes were generated with the floating point number in their designation, i.e. a01.0 or a1.00 and so on. in the case of a1.00 the compiler was confused as it expected a1.00 (as it was created in the first iteration by `\node[square,below=of a\i0] (a\k0) {};` where `\i` is an integer and `\k` is a float. Therefor, in the second iteration when `\i` equals to 1, but the node's designation is `a1.00` the compiler threw the error.
To support this here is another result of the code above including the two commented lines writing the results of the two macros into the boxes.

[image: Float vs integer values.]

Comment: That's my fault, in a way. When I initially answered to the OP previous question, I didn't realized that he would use it like this and didn't provide the correct macro `\pgfmathtruncatemacro`. @sorry: Maybe you should disclose your entire project, in order to let us find the best way to help you out ;)